# Batch EXIT followed by '|' - what is the purpose of this?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've never been one to really learn Windows/DOS Batch, but sometimes I dive into it to get some work done. I've seen the following construct in some legacy batch scripts, that I don't quite understand its intended function:

```
EXIT | some_external_command
```

What is the purpose of that? Maybe I'm missing something idiosyncratic (and yet vital/fundamental) of Windows Batch scripting.

Obviously `A|B` causes to execute `A` and to send its output to `B`.

But in this example, `EXIT` produces no output. As far as I can tell, it is equivalent to simply running the command on the right side of the '|' with no loss in function.

Is this construct intended to introduce some side effect that I'm not aware of? Just curious. Thanks.

Comment: You're right -- B gets its input from the result of A. Since EXIT has no result, there's no point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the programB.

See the difference for

```
EXIT | set /p .=abc
set /p .=abc
```

`EXIT` is used here to produce an empty input stream, this could also be done with other commands, like `CD` or `BREAK`.

This can be useful, if the program waits for input.

Comment: That is one obscure idiosyncrasy of Windows. Thanks!